# Google Ajax translate at Multiple parts of a page

Tags: google-translate

I want to use google ajax translate api to translate multiple parts of my page...

Iam using this code: 
http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlanguage/documentation/#Translate

But this will only translate the element in my page, that has the id="text".

But what i want is that, my page will contain multiple divs with id="text" and i want to translate all of them at a time, not only the first div content.

Is there any way i can tweak the javascript or how to achieve it?

Comment: Have anyone tried this ever? Please reply me if someone have atleast an idea.
My core task is to google translate more than 1 part of a page, at once, uisng their id. Is my only option is to have multiple ids in my page and write many translate functions to translate each id content ? Please suggest.